# msxml2 error on windows server 2012 (windows server2008 works well) (classic ASP)

Tags: asp-classic, windows-server-2012, msxml

i have a problem with windows server 2012.

I'm using following codes in ASP Classic for receive datas from another site.(which is http://www.tcmb.gov.tr)

`Set kurlar = Server.CreateObject("msxml.DOMDocument")
    kurlar.async = false`**this is row 144**
    `kurlar.resolveExternals = false
    kurlar.setProperty "ServerHTTPRequest" ,true
    kurlar.load("http://www.tcmb.gov.tr/kurlar/"&ay&"/"&gun&".xml")
Set sonuc = kurlar.getElementsByTagName("Currency")
    USDA=sonuc.item(0).childnodes.item(3).nodeTypedValue`**this is row 149**
    `USDS=sonuc.item(0).childnodes.item(4).nodeTypedValue
    EURA=sonuc.item(3).childnodes.item(3).nodeTypedValue
    EURS=sonuc.item(3).childnodes.item(4).nodeTypedValue`

**everything work very well on windows server 2008, windows 10 and windows 7 IIS but same code doesn't work on windows server 2012.**

**I receive following error;**

*Microsoft VBScript çalýþma hatasý hata '800a01a8'

Object required: 'sonuc.item(...)'

/work_task.asp, satır 149*

I've searched on Google, Stackowerflow and a lot of different sites and found some suggestions but still i receive error.

**some of what i've tried;**

*
* 
`Set kurlar = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")` to `Set kurlar = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")` also `Set kurlar = Server.CreateObject("msxml.DOMDocument")`

**Try to register** msxml6.dll and msxml4.dll again but didn't work :(

if i use `Set kurlar = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")` **instead of** `Set kurlar = Server.CreateObject("msxml.DOMDocument")`

this time i receive following error;

*Microsoft VBScript çalýþma hatasý hata '800a01b6'

object doesn't support this property or method: 'kurlar.async'

/work_task.asp, satır 144*

I've tried to find a solution last app. 8 hours i'm not expert on server 2008 or 2012 and MSXML.

Answer (score 0):

what a problem!!! i have solved it.

it's not about "MSXML" it's just about Microsoft has changed server 2012's date format..

in server 2008 date format is dd.mm.yyyy but in server 2012 date format is d.m.yyyy and my xml query is using date.